# interactive graph python wx.lib.plot. selecting some points

Tags: python

I have question and want to see if it can be realized in wxpython.
   I would like to plot data on wxpython, and then use the mouse to select some points which are plotted, using the mouse.
At the moment i am using wx.lib.plot and using the PlotMarker

Is there a way of doing this with wx.lib.plot or do i have to use another graph library

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably what you want can be done more conveniently using matplotlib (matplotlib canvas can be itself embedded in wxpython using [FigureCanvasWxAgg from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_wx5.html)).

In matplotlib you can select a point by using the picker property. [Here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html)  and [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/pick_event_demo2.html) you have examples of how to allow picking on the objects you draw and how to listen to the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use matplotlib or pygal. Something similar with your describing technique is used in PyQtGraph.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Chaco / TraitsUI for this sort of thing. They were developed specifically for interactive plots in Python. MAtplotlib / WX will work, but if you are going to be doing more of this sort of thing I found that Chaco was a better solution for interaction.

Here's some helpful links:

[Chaco Interactions](http://docs.enthought.com/chaco/user_manual/chaco_tutorial.html#plot-tools-adding-interactions)

[Line editing with Chaco](https://github.com/enthought/chaco/blob/master/examples/demo/edit_line.py)

[Scatter Plot Selection Example](https://github.com/enthought/chaco/blob/master/examples/demo/basic/scatter_inspector.py)

[Chaco Examples](http://docs.enthought.com/chaco/user_manual/annotated_examples.html#examples)